Number of solutions to the following equation $|z^2 + z + 1| = 1$
A question with the same equation is asked here but doesn't ask the same question as I do. So, it's not duplicate.
I'm given an equation $|z^2 + z + 1| = 1$, z is a complex number, and I need to tell if this equation has exactly four solutions or not.
So, while using the triangle inequalities, I found out

$|z^2 + \frac{1}{2}| \ge \frac{1}{2}$


$|z| \le 2$

But, I didn't use either of these informations to get the answer. I assumed another complex number $t = z + z^2$, and then my equation would something like this:
$|t + 1| = 1$
and this equation resembles the equation of a unit circle centered at $-1$ on the real axis.
So, $t$ would have infinite solutions.
And now something that seems extremely obvious, I'm having a hard time proving it.
To me it feels like I've done half the job, and now, I'm unable to prove (though I'm decent at visualizing, I'm not a good mathematician at proving things like these by hand).
How do I prove that because $t$, (which equals $z^2 + z$), has infinitely many solutions, $z$ would have infinitely many solutions too.
If you can tell me how to go about a question like this, or if there's something very general that I can keep in mind for the future, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks.

$|w|=1$ if and only if $w=e^{i t}$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Start there and solve a second degree algebraic equation to compute explicitly infinitely many solutions.

Adding to @BrianMoehring 's comment and picking from the answer below with $z=0 + i*0$ also a solution, that makes 5 which means there aren't just 4 solutions (if the objective is to just disprove that there are only 4 solutions).

Only $4$ solutions was option $(D)$ - so you are still talking about the duplicate? You said, it is a different question now.

@DietrichBurde Depends on your point of view.  On the one hand, the duplicate question (in effect) answers this posted question.  On the other hand, the other question might be construed as not a duplicate because an answer to this narrow question can not necessarily be transplanted into the other question.

@BrianMoehring, out of all the answers, (which are all wonderful By the way) your answer gives the most clarity, and makes it quite obvious to notice, why the solution set would be infinite. Would you write is an answer, short if you want, just like your comment, so that I can accept it as an answer.

@JimB z = 0 is a root that automatically follows from the first equation of Brian. So, your comment doesn't make any sense.

$z^2+z+1=1$ has two solutions.  $z^2+z+1=-1$ also has two solutions.  Can the same complex number appear as a solution to both?  No, of course not, since $1\neq -1$, so we already have four.  How many solutions does $z^2+z+1=i$ have?

I believe the solution set is an Oval of Cassini  Certainly not just four points.


A short description for Ovals of Cassini is: "square-root of a circle".  So we can see it in our equation $|z^2+z+1| = 1$.

It looks like there might be 6 integer solutions and 4 non negative imaginary part integer solutions.

@Mason Those are not integers, you could say those are Gaussian integers, but it's an important distinction.

Gaussian Integer Wiki

If $|z^2+z+1|=1$ then $z^2+z+1=(z+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}=e^{i t}$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$. So, you need to solve
$$w^2=e^{i t}-\frac{3}{4}=r e^{i s},$$
for some $r>0$ and some real number $s=s(t)$.
You see from here that you have infinitely many solutions that you can write out explicitly.


and I need to tell if this equation has exactly four solutions or not

Alternative approach, that (in light of the other responses) is inelegant.  However, this approach demonstrates that if the problem solver can glean no special insights to the problem, in any other manner, that this primitive approach is often reasonably effective, for this type of problem.
Set $~z = x + iy ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R}.~$
Then
$$z^2 + z + 1 = [ ~( ~x^2 - y^2 ~) + 2ixy ~] + [ ~x + iy ~] + 1 $$
$$= ( ~x^2 - y^2  + x + 1 ~) + i(2xy + y). \tag1 $$
Note that
$$| ~z^2 + z + 1 ~| = 1 \iff | ~z^2 + z + 1 ~|^2 = 1.$$
So, the problem reduces to determining whether it is possible for the following equation to have exactly $~4~$ distinct solutions in $~(x,y)$:
$$( ~x^2 - y^2  + x + 1 ~)^2 + (2xy + y)^2 = 1. \tag2 $$
There are three things of immediate note:

Expanding (2) above into a complicated 4th degree equation in $~x~$ and $~y~$ is messy, and is therefore a last resort.

All that the question is asking is whether (2) above has exactly $~4~$ solutions.

In (2) above, any value of $~y > 0~$ that generates a solution will also generate a solution in $~(-y) < 0.~$  That is, when you expand out the expression in (2) above, every occurrence of the variable $~y~$ will have form $~y^k~$ where $~k~$ is an even integer.


So, the obvious try is to take the first step of setting $~y = 0,~$ and $~y = 1,~$ and seeing where this leads.  Then, the plan of attack can be re-evaluated.

$\underline{y = 0}$
$$( ~x^2 + x + 1 ~)^2 = 1 \iff $$
$$[~ (x^2 + x + 1) + 1 ~] \times [ ~(x^2 + x + 1) - 1 ~] = 0 $$
$$\iff$$
$$[ ~(x^2 + x + 2) = 0 ~] ~~~~\text{or} ~~~~[ ~(x^2 + x) = 0 ~]. $$
Directly above, the LHS equation has no real solutions and the RHS has two real solutions.
So, when $~y = 0,~$ there are two real solutions.

$\underline{y = 1}$
$$( ~x^2 - 1 + x + 1 ~)^2 + ( ~2x + 1 ~)^2 = 1 \iff $$
$$( ~x^2 + x ~)^2 + ( ~2x + 1)^2 = 1 \iff $$
$$( ~x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 ~) + ( ~4x^2 + 4x + 1 ~) = 1 \iff $$
$$x^4 + 2x^3 + 5x^2 + 4x = 0 \iff $$
$$[ ~x = 0 ~] ~~~~\text{or} ~~~~ [ ~x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x + 4 = 0 ~].$$
Since $~-1 + 2 + -5 + 4 = 0,~$ you must have that $~x = -1 ~$ is a solution to the RHS equation above.
Therefore, when $~y = 1,~$ there are at least two solutions.
This makes it game over.

$\underline{\text{Final Analysis}}$
At this point, you know that:

When $~y = 0,~$ there are exactly two real solutions in $~x.~$

When $~y = 1,~$ there are at least two real solutions in $~x.~$

By the previous analysis, when $~y = -1,~$ there are at least two real solutions in $~x.~$


Therefore, it is impossible for the original equation in $~z~$ to have exactly $~4~$ solutions.

If looking at your equation 2, somehow we can identify that it forms an oval of Cassini, which I had no prior knowledge of before I looked at the answer of GEdgar, we can easily identify that it forms infinitely many solution.

@WebbWayne There is no avoiding that my approach is primitive (i.e. inelegant).  That being said, the idea was to solve the problem in the simplest manner possible.  A high school student will immediately grasp the idea of setting $~y=0~$ and $~y=1.$  There is no reason to even attempt to prove that there is an infinite number of solutions.

You're absolutely right. I am a high school student, and your approach was the one I instantly connected with. I was just mentioning a simple observation that I made.
